# Electrostatic potential energy stored in a system of point charges, where to use it?

Tags: electric-fields, charge, potential-energy

I'm approaching the potential of electrostatic field and before that, following my class' program, we prove that electrostatic field is conservative and therefore define the electrostatic potential energy due to a point charge $q$: given a point at a distance $R$ apart from the charge I have the following definition:

$$U_R = -\int\limits_{\infty}^{R} q\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{s} $$

Where the integral is to be evaluated along a curve from $\infty$ to the point $R$ (never mind which one due to conservativity). Now since we have the superposition principle for the electrostatic field and the potential energy is defined through an integral, which is a linear operator, I think it's safe to say that if I have multiple point charges then the total electrostatic potential energy can be computed adding up the single $U_i$ from the single point charges.

Anyways at a given point our textbook defines the electrostatic potential energy stored in a system of point charges as the work an external force has to spend to assemble the charges system starting from empty space (the first requires no work to be placed so if we have a single point charge in the system, the stored electrostatic potential energy would be zero, for the second one I have to go against the electric field due to the first one and so on), so at the end of the day the electrostatic potential energy stored in a system of $n$ point charges, let me still call it $U$, would be given by
$$U = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum\limits_{j=i+1}^{n} \dfrac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\dfrac{q_iq_j}{r_{ij}}$$
Where $r_{ij}$ denotes the distance between the $i-$th point charge and the $j-$th point charge. Now I think we can definitely use the first definition (electrostatic potential energy) in the energy conservation principle but I can't see how to use the second definition or where it can be useful. Could you please highlight the main differences between the two and their application? Thanks in advance!

Comment: They are the same thing. I don't understand the question.

Comment: @AaronStevens: Wait I'm confused: how are they the same thing if in the first case I need set a point in the space ($R$ in the question) whereas in the definition of electrostatic potential energy of a system of point charges there's none? (i.e. it depends on the system and not the particular point apparently?).

Comment: Put in $\mathbf E$ for a point charge and find the change in potential energy to bring in another charge from $\infty$ to some distance $r$. Then add all of those up as you bring in each charge. You get your second equation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two equations are the same for a system of point particles. I will show how.

First, let's consider a point charge $q_i$ at the origin. The field $\mathbf E(\mathbf r)$ produced by this charge is given by
$$\mathbf E=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{q_i}{|\mathbf r|^2}\hat r$$

Now, let's bring in another charge $q_j$ from infinity to position $\mathbf R$ and determine the change in potential energy of the system using your first equation
$$\Delta U=-\int_{\infty}^{R}q_j\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{q_i}{|\mathbf r|^2}\hat r\cdot \text d\mathbf r=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{q_iq_j}{|\mathbf R|}$$

Now, this was for $q_i$ at the origin, but you could generalize this using a bit more mathematical rigor, or just think about translating the coordinate system, and conclude that if I have one point charge $q_i$ located at position $\mathbf r_i$ and then I bring in charge $q_j$ from infinity to position $\mathbf r_j$ that my change in potential energy will be given by
$$\Delta U=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{q_iq_j}{r_{i,j}}$$
where $r_{i,j}=|\mathbf r_i-\mathbf r_j|$.

---

Ok, so now let's say we have a configuration of $n$ point charges. Let's think about the total change in potential energy in constructing this configuration by bringing in each charge from infinity.

Let's bring in charge $q_n$ first for free, as there are no other charges present.

Next, let's bring in charge $q_{n-1}$. It interacts with charge $q_n$ and we have a change in potential energy
$$\Delta U=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{q_{n-1}q_{n}}{r_{n-1,n}}$$

Next let's bring in charge $q_{n-2}$. It interacts with both $q_{n-1}$ and $q_{n}$. So our running total for the total change in potential energy will be

$$\Delta U=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\left(\frac{q_{n-1}q_{n}}{r_{n-1,n}}\right)+\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\left(\frac{q_{n-2}q_{n-1}}{r_{n-2,n-1}}+\frac{q_{n-2}q_{n}}{r_{n-2,n}}\right)$$

And if we kept going all of the way to $q_1$ we would have

$$\Delta U=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\left(\frac{q_{n-1}q_{n}}{r_{n-1,n}}\right)+\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\left(\frac{q_{n-2}q_{n-1}}{r_{n-2,n-1}}+\frac{q_{n-2}q_{n}}{r_{n-2,n}}\right)+\dots+\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\left(\frac{q_1q_2}{r_{1,2}}+\frac{q_{1}q_{3}}{r_{1,3}}+\dots+\frac{q_1q_n}{r_{1,n}}\right)$$

Rewriting each term more compactly we have
$$\Delta U=\left(\sum_{j=n}^{n}\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{q_{n-1}q_j}{r_{n-1,j}}\right)+\left(\sum_{j=n-1}^{n}\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{q_{n-2}q_j}{r_{n-2,j}}\right)+\dots+\left(\sum_{j=2}^{n}\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{q_{1}q_j}{r_{1,j}}\right)$$

Compacting further we finally arrive at
$$\Delta U=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^n\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{q_iq_j}{r_{i,j}}$$
which is your second equation.

Therefore, each equation is giving you the same thing for your configuration of point charges. The first tells you how moving each charge contributes to the potential energy. The second is just the sum of all contributions as determined by the first.

Answer (score 1):

Potential energy is defined for a system i.e two or more charges. Since electric field is conservative, the work done by it is the change in the potential energy of the system. Using work energy theorem, work done by field is the negative of the work done by external force. Since work done by a conservative field is the negative of change in the potential energy of the system, the work done by external force comes out to be equal to the change in potential energy of system. Think of it this way, you have n charges all at infinity. Now to create a system you do some work to bring those charges from infinity to some point. The work done by you has been converted into the potential energy of the newly formed system.

Comment: in which cases the potential energy of the system is to be used over the integral and superposition principle?